# simple quotes on git windows with curl

Tags: windows, git, curl, github, libcurl

i am trying to push a local repository to github in windows.

i have the problem with simple quotes in a commit so i just put double quotes and that solve the problem.

but now i am trying to push and this tell me that

i am doing this in a new local repo

```
cd folder
git init
git add --all
git commit -m "commit"
git config remote.origin.url https://...../repo.git
git push -u origin master
```

fatal unable to access 'https://........' protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl

i read that curl can have problems with the url in simple quotes, i think that can be the problem, but i don't know how to change the git config to use double quotes instead of simple quotes in a push. anyone knows how to do that?

or if this can be solved in other way, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unrelated to the quotes. The libcurl your git is using was simply built without HTTPS support. You need a libcurl built *with* HTTPS support to be able to use git repositories over HTTPS.

Comment: i download a new executable of curl and install it, that says that have https support, but the problem is still there. how can I test if this have https ennabled? or another idea?